# Google Map API v3 not loading in IE9

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, google-maps-api-3

I researched the topic as much as I could but didn't find a solution.

In all browsers except Internet Explorer (versions 8 or 9), the script below will work for loading Google maps. In **IE8** and **IE9**, however, the Google maps API (v3) does not seem to load. I have looked to find specific errors in the console, but found nothing.

**Html**

```
<style type="text/css">
    #map_canvas { 
        height: 292; 
        width:980 
    }

    .contactus-Captcha {
        clear:both;
    }
</style>

<div id="map_canvas"></div>
```

**Javascript**

```
function initialize() {
            var homeLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(29.70280,-95.51731);

            var myOptions = {
                zoom: 15,
                center: homeLatlng,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            };

            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);


                var contentString = '<div id="content">'+
                        '<div id="siteNotice">'+
                        '</div>'+
                        '<h3>ABC</h3>'+
                        '<div id="bodyContent">'+
                        '<div class="AddressWrap"><div style="width:100%; margin:1 auto; float:left;"><img src="<?php echo ROOTPATH; ?>images/location-icon.png" style="float:left; padding-right:5px;"> <h3 class="Marker"> xyz</h3></div><h3 class="Mobile"> <img src="<?php echo ROOTPATH; ?>images/mob-icon2.png" style="float:left; padding-right:12px; "> 123445</h3></div>'+
                        '</div>'+
                        '</div>';
                    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                        content: contentString
                    });

            var image = new google.maps.MarkerImage(        
                '<?php echo ROOTPATH; ?>images/addres-icon.png',
                new google.maps.Size(32, 32),   // size
                new google.maps.Point(0,0), // origin
                new google.maps.Point(16, 32)   // anchor
            );

            var shadow = new google.maps.MarkerImage(
                'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/micons/msmarker.shadow.png',
                new google.maps.Size(59, 32),   // size
                new google.maps.Point(0,0), // origin
                new google.maps.Point(16, 32)   // anchor
            );

            var homeMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: homeLatlng, 
                map: map,
                title: "xyz",
                icon: image,
                shadow: shadow
            });
            google.maps.event.addListener(homeMarker, 'click', function() {
                        infowindow.open(map,homeMarker);
                    });
        }    

  $(document).ready(function() {            
    initialize(); //Calling on load
  });
```

Can anyone help me out? I would be very thankful!

Comment: Do you load via http:// or https://?

Comment: I am using http protocol..

Comment: @Thanks Brad for nice edit...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your map doesn't have a size.  Change:

```
#map_canvas { height: 292; width:980 }
```

To:

```
#map_canvas { height: 292px; width:980px }
```